# Is it possible to disable/enable ContextMenuStrip items?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have created a `ContextMenuStrip1` in my form project.

Is it possible to modify the items in the code? For instance, I would like to disable some buttons or perhaps edit their text.

I though about modifying the items property, but it is readOnly.

Comment: The items have Enabled, Visible, and Text properties.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: Oh, you're right. Feel free to post the answer.